# PDF editor/viewer for Linux/Windows with element positioning options

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Is there some PDF editor/viewer for Linux or Windows that can show me a position of selected element and document size in inches?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a console tool written in Ruby called [pdf-extract](https://github.com/CrossRef/pdfextract), which is able to show text regions and document size in pixels. I'm not sure will it work for Windows, but in Linux it works pretty nice (except that its dependency pdf-reader version 1.1.1 should be installed, higher version don't work).

Example usage:

```
pdf-extract extract --regions file.pdf
```

Example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pdf>
  <page width="612" height="792" number="1">
    <region x="40.73" y="682.68" width="62.53" height="4.47" line_height="4.47" font="CHRUEN+MetaPlusMedium-Roman">
      <line x_offset="0.0" y_offset="0.0" spacing="0.0">xxxx</line>
    </region>
    <region x="41.65" y="669.18" width="60.69" height="4.47" line_height="4.47" font="CHRUEN+MetaPlusMedium-Roman">
      <line x_offset="0.0" y_offset="0.0" spacing="0.0">xxxx</line>
    </region>
    <region x="40.81" y="655.68" width="62.38" height="4.47" line_height="4.47" font="CHRUEN+MetaPlusMedium-Roman">
      <line x_offset="0.0" y_offset="0.0" spacing="0.0">xxxx</line>
    </region>
    <region x="19.48" y="640.69" width="5.86" height="5.9" line_height="5.9" font="XBCKNX+AGaramond-Italic">
      <line x_offset="0.0" y_offset="0.0" spacing="0.0">xxx</line>
    </region>
    <region x="27.44" y="640.69" width="97.07" height="5.96" line_height="4.47" font="CHRUEN+MetaPlusMedium-Roman">
      <line x_offset="0.0" y_offset="1.49" spacing="0.0">xxx</line>
      <line x_offset="44.96" y_offset="0.0" spacing="-4.42">xxx</line>
    </region>
    <region x="43.18" y="628.68" width="57.64" height="4.47" line_height="4.47" font="CHRUEN+MetaPlusMedium-Roman">
      <line x_offset="0.0" y_offset="0.0" spacing="0.0">xxxx</line>
    </region>
  </page>
</pdf>
```

Where "xxx" is actual text